# javascript parameter passing in dynamic action handler

Tags: javascript

I need to create several Divs dynamically, and I need to add "onmouseover" event to them. However, the JAVASCRIPT "div.onmouseover = handler" can't pass in parameters. **how can I pass parameters in those dynamic event handlers?**

Comment: What parameters do you want passed in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) to do this:

```
function createHandlerFor(a, b, c) {
    return function(event) {
        // This function will be called later, and it has access
        // to 'a', 'b', and 'c'
    };
}
```

Or using a named function (my preference, so call stacks and such are clearer);

```
function createHandlerFor(a, b, c) {
    function myNiftyHandler(event) {
        // This function will be called later, and it has access
        // to 'a', 'b', and 'c'
    };
    return myNiftyHandler;
}
```

Use:

```
div.onmouseover = createHandler(1, 2, "three");
```

...or hook it up via `addEventListener` (standards) or `attachEvent` (IE < 8).

Although you could define the handler inline, doing so "closes over" everything that's in scope where you define it. Using a separate function and passing it parameters keeps the closure as small as possible, which is useful for memory management.

Closures are not complicated, but they have some interesting properties. [More here.](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures).

```
div.onmouseover = function(){ handler(arguments,here); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) to do this:

```
myParam = "test";
div.onmouseover = function(){ alert(myParam); }
```