# Javascript function as parameter to other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function addValidEvent(item,event,func)
{
    if (item.addEventListener) 
    {
        item.addEventListener(event, func, false);        
    }
    else 
    if (item.attachEvent) 
    {
        item.attachEvent("on" + event, func);
    } else {
       //todo
    }
}
```

I call it like

```
addValidEvent(element, "mouseover", inRadio(element));
```

inRadio this is other function, I need to register this with out call a inRadio in addValidEvent call.

How to correct pass the function like param ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript parameter passing in dynamic action handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571655/javascript-parameter-passing-in-dynamic-action-handler)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context on which your function is called is the element itself, so you could pass the function reference(name) as the event handler:

```
addValidEvent(element, "mouseover", inRadio);
```

or  you can wrap your function call in an anonymous function(this might come in handy when you want to have more control over the callback) :

```
addValidEvent(element, "mouseover", function(){inRadio(element);});
```

Answer (score 4):

pass it as function. Now you are calling method inRadio. Do it like this

```
addValidEvent(element, "mouseover", function() {inRadio(element); });
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are actually calling the function and the return value of that call is being passed as thrid argumnent to `addValidEvent` method.

Try this.

```
addValidEvent(element, "mouseover", inRadio);
```

As a side note: Since jQuery is tagged to this question I would suggest you to use jQuery for this which is so simple.

```
$(element).mouseover(inRadio);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = function() {
    // code here
}
```

Then do what you need to with 'a'

But I prefer the previous answers :)

Comment: How is this helpful? I fail to see a relation to the question.

Comment: I'd still say this is an rather incomplete example. It is not clear how `a` integrates with the existing code.

Comment: I did not say that ;) Anyways, I understand the problem, I just want to encourage you to improve your answer. All you show is how to create a function, which I suppose to OP already knows.