# Create new function in contentScriptFile in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a firefox extension in which I've these functions in contentScriptFile of myPanel:

```
...
function myFun(param){
    console.log("myFun with "+param)
}

self.port.on('myTrigger',function(value){
    $("#myFavDiv").append("<a onclick='myFun(\'"+value+"\')'> click me!</a>")
});
...
```

I'm including script file like (in `main.js`):

```
myPanel = panel.Panel({
  width: 400,
  height: 200,
  contentURL: self.data.url("panel.html"),
  contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery-1.10.2.min.js") , self.data.url("mScript.js")]
});
```

Everything is working fine, just the problem is `onclick` method which is with dynamically added anchor tag in `div#myFavDiv`

Error thrown when I click anchor:

```
Timestamp: 8/10/2013 1:24:48 AM
Error: ReferenceError: myFun is not defined
```

I tried to write this `myFun` function in `main.js` still same error is there.

Any idea(s)/solution(s)?

Answer (score 2):

I think the content script is being sandboxed from the HTML, so when the anchor is injected into the HTML, it doesn't know what `myFun` is. Within your content script, you can just bind the handler there, keeping it within the same environment.

```
self.port.on('myTrigger',function(value){
    $("#myFavDiv").append("<a onclick='myFun(\'"+value+"\')'> click me!</a>")
    $("#myFaDiv a").click(myFun);
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks, From your answer I got to know that I've to add click event separately. But I also need to pass dynamic arguments with this click event. I got my solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571655/javascript-parameter-passing-in-dynamic-action-handler & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FClosures 
Thanks for you help. My problem is solved now.

Comment: I'll soon release plugin Songs.pk Auto Downloader you can check it out. Thanks again.